# Problems working with Rgui in Win7.64-bit...gibberish non-english characters

Tags: r, amazon-s3, rgui

I have some problems with the execution of R GUI in Windows 7/64-bit. It appears gibberish while running R terminal sounds ok. here are the pictures of the two. I searched the web but I have no clue.
[image]
[image]